# How to show the numbers on the y-axis by 1 on HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have couple of charts working but whenever the chart spline is on 1-3 the yAxis shows numbers like 0.25, 0.75, 1.50 etc.. The spline is correct but i want to show only full numbers on the yAxis e.g 1,2,3,4,5 etc..

Any way to do that?

Comment: what have you specified in  `yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'title text'
        }
    }`

Comment: Already fixed that, someone just helped me on their forum, see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed with :

```
allowDecimals: false
```

Thanks.